# onChange event is not fired for lightning:input type="datetime" when clear Time field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, datetime, date-picker

I have the following component:

**Example.cmp**

```
    <lightning:input
        aura:id="field"
        type="datetime"
        name="datetimeInput"
        label="Set up a date/time"
        value="{! v.scheduleDatetime }"
        required="true"
        onchange="{! c.onChange }"
    />

</aura:component>
```

**ExampleController.js**

```
onChange: function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log("onChange", event.getSource().get("v.value"));
    const target = event.getSource();
}
```

[image]

When I select a date, the time part is populated automatically. I see the console log for the `onchange` event:

```
onChange 2019-05-28T22:30:00.000Z
```

It also works when I change time value. So far so good.

[image]

But when I clear the time part, the `onchange` event is not fired. And the value of this component remains `2019-05-28T22:30:00.000Z`. This is awkward because I expect the value to become either `2019-05-28T00:00:00.000` or null (which is better).

[image]

I need to be able to catch `onchange` events for such cases, or at least get the correct value when run my custom validation. Now when I access component value during validation `component.find("field").get("v.value")`, I see the last valid datetime value, not the current one with the time part cleared. This means that users can submit the form when the Time is empty, whereas it's not actually empty... This is confusing.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your problem correctly, I think you make use of the validity property as described in the documentation. So instead of checking the null values, you can directly check if the field is valid using the below code.

```
var validity = component.find("field").get("v.validity");
console.log("Is it valid? ", validity.valid); //returns true
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: How can we do the same in lwc?