# onChange event is not fired for lightning:input type="datetime" when clear Time field in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, datetime, page-validation

I have an lwc `lightning-input` datetime field and a custom validation. It does not work when the I clear the time value out of it. This is similar to what's mentioned in [this link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/264264/62544).

However, I am looking for the same solution in LWC, and NOT in aura. How can I approach this?

Comment: Do you mind sharing your HTML and JS codes please? It can help in providing a good response, especially the custom validation that you are performing

Comment: This will fix your problem - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/382201/change-even-on-datetime-input-field-does-not-track-time . If you still want to handle time change event , add a handler for `onkeyup` for `lightning-input`

Comment: @Rohit Yes this worked

Comment: Yes @DavidCheng